# NodeJs installed but getting error "Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the template available on this [link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) to create an Angular 2 App with ASP Core 1.1.

I can run the application in Production/Development mode just fine via Visual Studio 2017.

But I am getting an error when published on IIS 10.0 on Windows 10.

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Failed to start Node process. To
>   resolve this:.
>
> [1](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the
>   PATH directories.

I have set the path in PATH environment variable where I have NodeJS installed.

In addition, I am able to invoke the exe from published folder from command prompt and when I go to the URL it is opening fine as well. Now I have read somewhere on github that this is due to some issue at IIS Integration but I am not able to find anything on Internet so far.

I would appreciate any help or guidence to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you try running it as an administrator?

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio after installing NodeJS? Any program or shell will gather the PATH directories on startup, they're not dynamically reloaded when one is added.

Comment: yes, i even restarted the system. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @Blastfreak Application is running fine from VS, I am not sure if i need to run IIS as admin to resolve this issue.

Comment: @NewUser546 hello i faced with this problem, do you hace solution?

Comment: @user3373603 My apologies for late reply. I had to install following utilities on server in order for it to work.
1. IIS Node Module
2. DotNetCore Runtime 
3. NodeJS (It was already installed)